# Botão com fundo transparente

Tags: android

estou criando botão na minha aplicação assim

```
final Button btCategoria = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button, null);
        btCategoria.setId((int) listenerCategoria.id);
        btCategoria.setText(listenerCategoria.nome+"("+getSize((int) listenerCategoria.id)+" fotos)");
```

**Layout**

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:id="@+id/btCategoria" />
```

deste jeito o botão fica com o fundo totalmente transparente, queria saber se tem algum modo de deixar parcialmente transparente, algum jeito de controlar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo *XML*, pode ser algo assim:

```
android:background="#66000000"
```

Onde **66** representa [40% de 255](https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=UiTZVLjeDauX8Qfg6YHACQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=40%25%20of%20255%20to%20hex) e o restante é a cor sólida, neste caso o preto.

Ou dinamicamente, após definir a cor sólida do seu botão:

```
btCategoria.getBackground().setAlpha(102);
```

Onde este valor inteiro vai de `0` (totalmente transparente) a `255` (totalmente opaco).